# Convert web service xml object into java class

Tags: xml, web-services, jaxb

I'm currently converting a number of web services from plain xml. I've load them in soapUI, created a client port and mock service and the request response is working perfectly. So right now I'm trying to create/convert the xml complex type objects into java, but I'm failing.

In soapUI I have this as a response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cli="http://client.serviceweb.xxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cli:versionResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <result xsi:type="java:ResultatVersion" xmlns:java="java:xxx.serviceweb">
            <messagexxx xsi:type="xsd:string">message</messagexxx>
            <resultatxxx xsi:type="xsd:int">1</resultatxxx>
            <version xsi:type="java:Version">
               <numero xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0.0</numero>
            </version>
         </result>
      </cli:versionResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any idea how to convert that to a java object? Looking at the original xml there's a parent object that contains the field message and result, but I don't understand the version part.

How about this one?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xxx="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cli="http://client.serviceweb.xxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cli:testResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <result xsi:type="java:ResultatImage" xmlns:java="java:xxx.serviceweb.xxx.xxx">
            <messagexxx xsi:type="xxx:string">message</messagexxx>
            <resultatxxx xsi:type="xxx:int">result</resultatxxx>
            <image xsi:type="xxx:base64Binary">cid:1325182441595</image>
         </result>
      </cli:testResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I already have a working Jaxb client that I have used previously and is already working, but can't figure out how to call the above samples.

I'm having:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{}resultatImage>
```

Seems like the response is not mapping to the ResultatImage class that I've created.

Any thoughts?

How I send the request and unmarshall the response.

```
try {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext
            .newInstance("com.ipiel.response");
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    client = new MyClient(httpClient, targetHost, u);
    client.test();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public void test() {
    String url = "/xxxClientsPort/test";
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpPost);
    log.info("response: " + response);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (respEntity != null) {
            InputStream instream = respEntity.getContent();
            try {
                ResultatImage responseEntity = (ResultatImage) unmarshaller
                        .unmarshal(instream);
                /*
                 * FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new
                 * File("c:\\tmp\\output")); IOUtils.copy(instream, writer,
                 * "UTF-8"); String theString = writer.toString();
                 * writer.flush(); writer.close();
                 * System.out.println(theString);
                 */
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

package com.ipiel.response has the class Resultat and ResultatImage, both marked as @XmlRootElement. Also it contains the ObjectFactory marked as @XmlRegistry

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here was that I was generating the java classes inside SoapUI using the wrong version of Axis. I was trying with Axis2, but later found out that the webservice is actually running on Axis1. So if you ever encounter a similar problem, check first if the webservice version and the library of your client is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You load web-service to SOAP UI using WSDL. Wsdl contains schemas of the class.
For converting WSDL to Java classes you can use plugin for Eclipse
[wsdl2java plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/)

or you can use maven plugins, like

```
<groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
<artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

and

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I'm aware of the wsdltojava, but I don't want to create client stubs. I'm using JAXBContext and Unmarshaller. I've appended the above the code that sends the request and unmarshall the response.